# The method setBackground(Color) is undefined for the type Color

Tags: java, swing

I am making a color changing RGB slider. For some reason, I keep getting this error at line 47. I've tried all of the suggested things from eclipse, none have actually worked. I'm stumped on what to do.

```
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener; 
import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.GridLayout; 


public class SliderPanel extends JPanel implements ChangeListener { 

    private Color CP;
    private JSlider green;
    private JSlider blue;
    private JSlider red;

public SliderPanel (Color color) { 
    CP = color; 

    green = new JSlider(0,255,0);
    green.setPaintTicks(true); 
    green.setPaintLabels(true); 
    green.setMajorTickSpacing(15); 
    green.addChangeListener(this); 

    blue = new JSlider(0,0,255);
    blue.setPaintTicks(true); 
    blue.setPaintLabels(true); 
    blue.setMajorTickSpacing(15); 
    blue.addChangeListener(this); 

    red = new JSlider(255,0,0);
    red.setPaintTicks(true); 
    red.setPaintLabels(true); 
    red.setMajorTickSpacing(15); 
    red.addChangeListener(this); 

    setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1)); 

    add(green); 
    add(blue);
    add(red); 

} 

public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

    CP.setBackground(new Color(green.getValue(), blue.getValue(), red.getValue())); 

} 
}
```

Also, I am getting an error in the main class that says this 
"The constructor SliderPanel(ColorPanel) is undefined"

Here is the code that is in question.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component; 

    public class Main extends JPanel { 
        private SliderPanel SP;
        private ColorPanel CP; 

    public Main() { 
        CP = new ColorPanel();  
        SP = new SliderPanel(CP);


        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(CP, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(SP, BorderLayout.NORTH); 
    }
    }
```

Comment: You are attempting to call the setBackground method on the Color object. I would assume that setBackground is a method of the ColorPanel class and not the Color class.

In your main function you declare that CP = new ColorPanel() however in your SliderPanel class you say that CP = color, which is an instance of the Color class.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. Thank you. Now I'm not sure if it will compile however, because I'm getting an error Error: Could not find or load main class. Even though that file isn't in the same project as this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

```
CP = new Color(green.getValue(), blue.getValue(), red.getValue());
```

}

You can't set background for a Color Object.